# How to allow cell navigation in SlickGrid with a Validation Error?

Tags: slickgrid

I've noticed that when a validation error occurs, the user is locked into that cell until the error is resolved. Is there a way to allow the user to continue to navigate cells?

This approach works for me b/c I don't commit when they leave the cell, but wait until they click a Save button. So, this button would be disabled while an error exists, but they are still free to navigate cells. Thank you.

Comment: did you ever found out how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own `editorLock` function, that is passed to options. This feature, just as most of SlickGrid, is poorly documented, ut you can watch through source code of [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js), and search for function called `commitCurrentEdit`.

The example of `editorLock` is in the file `slick.core.js`

Also, before rendering the grid you can try to do this:

```
Slick.GlobalEditorLock.commitCurrentEdit = function(){
    return true;
}
```